# EAS development build failing - @babel/util/-/helpers no such package found

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm trying to build my expo managed react native project and I'm running into an issues when installing dependencies. The command I'm running is:

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

EAS error logs:

```
Running "npm install" in /Users/expo/workingdir/build directory
npm WARN
deprecated @types/react-native@0.73.0: This is a stub types definition. react-native provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm
WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm
WARN
deprecated
uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from@7.18.9: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from instead.
npm WARN deprecated
@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm WARN deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated
uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated
uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm
ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://10.94.183.70:4873/@babel/util/-/helpers-7.23.8.tgz - no such package available
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@babel/helpers@http://10.94.183.70:4873/@babel/util/-/helpers-7.23.8.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR!
404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR!
A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/expo/.npm/_logs/2024-01-23T23_51_47_434Z-debug-0.log
Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Install dependencies build phase for more information.
```

The app works perfectly when I run it in expo go, but I'm at the stage where I need native modules so I need to eject from expo go.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you cant just copy and paste eas.json from one project to another and hope things will work out. My eas.json had:

```
 "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.13.0"
  },
```

After running this comand:

```
eas build:configure
```

I ended up with a new eas.json containing:

```
 "cli": {
    "version": ">= 7.0.0"
  },
```

I was then able to copy in all my build settings from the old file. But the cli version seems critical.